# verify_grad function: 'TensorVariable' object is not callable

Tags: python, theano

I'd like to use the verify_grad function, but I'm getting errors of the form "'TensorVariable' object is not callable".

```
theano.gradient.verify_grad(fun, pt, n_tests=2, rng=None, eps=None, out_type=None, abs_tol=None, rel_tol=None, mode=None, cast_to_output_type=False)
```

In the doc it says that fun is "a Python function that takes Theano variables as inputs, and returns a Theano variable. For instance, an Op instance with a single output."

I have gone through the graph structures section in the docs and I thought I understood what an op node is, but apparently I don't.

E.g. if I have two TensorVariables x and y and I'd like to take the product of them, then * is the op node, correct? But if I declare z=x*y, then z is again a TensorVariable, right?

So is there any way how to define an op for e.g. a negative log likelihood function in order to evaluate the correctness of the gradient for that function? Or is there any other way to get the numerical gradient in theano for a function that you constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of `verify_grad` in use:

```
import numpy
import theano

def something_complicated(x, y):
    z = x * y
    return z

x_value = numpy.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
y_value = numpy.array([[7., 8., 9.], [10., 11., 12.]], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
theano.gradient.verify_grad(something_complicated, (x_value, y_value), rng=numpy.random)
```

As required, `something_complicated` is "a Python function that takes Theano variables as inputs [`x` and `y` in this case], and returns a Theano variable [`z` in this case]."

You can construct any symbolic expression inside `something_complicated`, such as the computation for a negative log likelihood.

A Theano operation can be anything as long as

1. It is *callable* (objects are callable if they implement the special [`__call__` function](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__))
2. When it is called, it treats all inputs as Theano variables
3. When it is called, it only returns Theano variables.

`something_complicated` clearly meets these requirements. It is callable by virtue of being a Python function, it assumes `x` and `y` are Theano variables, and its return value `z` is also a Theano variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful. They should put that example in the docs.